# How to check if an object has been already created?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

Hello i would like to check if an object was created. If its created then redirect to the id page but if it isnt created redirect to the page where its being created.

Here is my app

```html
app.get('/my',isLoggedIn,async (req,res)=> {
    const safe= await Safe.find({});
    if(safe===undefined){
        res.redirect('/mysafe')
    }
    else {
         res.redirect(`mysafe/${safe._id}`)
    }
})
```

i think it should work but im getting a cast error
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Safe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to flip your conditional and use `if(safe)` as the condition. That will be true if the object has been created and false if not. Something along the lines of:

```js
app.get('/my', isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
    const safe= await Safe.find({});
    if(safe){
        res.redirect(`mysafe/${safe._id}`)
    } else {
        res.redirect('/mysafe')
    }
})
```